# Converter datatables em ASP.NET para diferentes SHEETS do Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-excel, gridview

Como posso criar mais que um `sheets` convertendo diferentes `datatable` para excel?
Meu código:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = Tr.Get();
        GridView x = new GridView();
        x.DataSource = dt;
        x.DataBind();
        Response.Clear();
        x.HeaderStyle.Font.Size = 8;
        x.RowStyle.Font.Size = 10;

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=s.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        x.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);

        Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());

        Response.End();
```

Comment: Podes usar OleDb para criar o documento Excel: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/. Não sei se funciona em aplicações web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que no seu caso, uma boa solução seria usar o EpPlus que está disponivel via NuGet

Mais detalhes nesta outra questao do StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425339/export-multiple-datagrids-to-different-worksheets-on-a-single-excel-file